# Is there a way to prevent "half-dots" on this border?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a "lightbulb chain" using the dotted border, but when I make the left and bottom border transparent, it leaves me with these "half-dots", which kills the illusion.

Is there anyway to do this without the dots being cut in half?

```css
.chain {
height: 300px;
width: 50px;
border: 5px dotted black;
border-color: #000 #000 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="chain"></div>
```

Comment: using the **border-radius** could help here, if the style does not conflict with you solution

Comment: @vucko instead of turning this into a puzzle trail, you could also link directly to that "excellent answer".

Comment: @Vucko I am also curious to know that *excellent* answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif well, it's [well explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073558/1763929) how border works. But okey, I'll remove my vote to close, but it may be helpful for the link to stay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing **half-dots** because you have set border to all side(top, right, bottom, left). So the fix for this problem is to only set `border-top` and `border-right` instead of setting border to all side.

```css
.chain {
height: 300px;
width: 50px;
border-top: 5px dotted black;
border-right: 5px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="chain"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As with most things in CSS, there are probably many ways to do this. Here's one.

```css
    .container{
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     left: 5px;
     top: -7px;
    }
    
    .chain {
     position: relative;
     left: -5px;
     top: 7px;
     height: 300px;
     width: 50px;
     border: 5px dotted black;
     border-color: #000 #000 transparent transparent;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
     <div class="chain"></div>
    </div>
```

Basically, you're hiding the last dot on the left and bottom ends of the border.

Comment: Ah, that's some "out-of-the-box" thinking! :D Just thought maybe there would be some property that might also remove it. This works just fine. Thank you!